# Mysql how to update a colum after a time automatically?

Tags: mysql

I want that when user paid or not paid.

```
if paid status = 1
and when not paid status = 0
```

And now in paid case I want that it automatically change 0 after a time. How can I do this?

Comment: after what time? Is the  time in the same row as the table? What is the table? Another usual way is  `SELECT ... WHERE due > NOW()` and have a result depending on that comparison.

Comment: when user pay the time of pay is inserted in row. and after one year from time in row i want that it will change 0 paid status

Comment: Maybe MySQL [events](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong method. You should avoid structures that need bulk updating as they will become large and burdensome. They will also be hard to change.

Recommend having an expired date. Queries for validity would be `SELECT .. WHERE NOW() <= expired`.

When a user does pay, their column expired date get set at `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`.